# Destroy a customer/orders in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, http, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello fellow programmers, I have been working on a order management system. I finally have worked out all my errors except for one i cant get out. Once i delete a customer or a order i get a error message saying "Routing error".

> Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/customers/2"
>
> Rails.root: /Users/cecil/Desktop/order_management_systeem
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace Routes

This is my route

```
           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action
    customer_orders GET    /customers/:customer_id/orders(.:format)          orders#index
                    POST   /customers/:customer_id/orders(.:format)          orders#create
 new_customer_order GET    /customers/:customer_id/orders/new(.:format)      orders#new
edit_customer_order GET    /customers/:customer_id/orders/:id/edit(.:format) orders#edit
     customer_order GET    /customers/:customer_id/orders/:id(.:format)      orders#show
                    PATCH  /customers/:customer_id/orders/:id(.:format)      orders#update
                    PUT    /customers/:customer_id/orders/:id(.:format)      orders#update
                    DELETE /customers/:customer_id/orders/:id(.:format)      orders#destroy
          customers GET    /customers(.:format)                              customers#index
                    POST   /customers(.:format)                              customers#create
       new_customer GET    /customers/new(.:format)                          customers#new
      edit_customer GET    /customers/:id/edit(.:format)                     customers#edit
           customer GET    /customers/:id(.:format)                          customers#show
                    PATCH  /customers/:id(.:format)                          customers#update
                    PUT    /customers/:id(.:format)                          customers#update
                    DELETE /customers/:id(.:format)                          customers#destroy
                    GET    /:controller/:action/:id/:customer_id(.:format)   :controller#:action
```

this is my erb code

```
<%= link_to("Delete", customer_path(@customer), method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?", :class => 'action delete') %>
```

Destroy controller

```
 def destroy
    customer = Customer.find(params[:id]).destroy 
    flash[:notice] = "Subject '#{customer.first_name}' destroyed successfully"
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end
```

Comment: please update the question with controller's actions (`destroy`)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Thanks for the tip

Comment: I meant the code from controller action called `destroy` :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Done!

Comment: You seem to be missing the @ on at customer in your destroy action. It's important that customer is specified as an instance variable in your controller to be able to pass this to the view.

Comment: @CecilBoye in case my answer would (and it would indeed) solve your issue, consider accepting it (checkmark on the left side of the answer) - I noticed you never accepted a single answer yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action destroy should look as something along the following lines:

```
def destroy
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id]
  @customer.destroy
  redirect_to(
    customers_path,
    notice: 'Customer successfully deleted'
  )
end
```

Also edits to link:

```
<%= link_to("Delete", @customer, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }) %>
```

The problem in your case, is that you've defined variable `customer`, but use `@customer` in your url_helper (`customer_path(@customer)`).

Another thing (more important), is that you actually assign a `customer`  a value, which is *the result of deleting an object from database*:

```
customer = Customer.find(params[:id]).destroy
```

Never do so.

Either do

```
Customer.find(params[:id]).destroy
```

or

```
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@customer.destroy
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable advice, It still seems not to work. When i inspect element on the link i get this (<a class="action show" confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="destroy" href="/customers/2">Delete</a>)  Maybe a dumb question but does it has something to do with bootstrap?

Comment: Yes i have, and i get the same result.

Comment: Dont work either, i also have a delete action, does it have any effect with the procedure?

Comment: do not have the delete action, comment it out - why do you have it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96973/discussion-between-cecil-boye-and-andrey-deineko).